# Displaying Subpages while on Parent page?

Tags: pages, navigation

I would like to create a navigation menu where I will be displaying two level pages.

To illustrate that:

- Parent 1
- Parent 2
- Parent 3 (current)

  - Child 1
  - Child 2
  - Child 3
- Parent 4

So I would like to display all the parent pages in my navigation container but only display children pages when the user is currently on its parent page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy, as WordPress sets css classes for the parent pages.
Default we hide all sublists (ul) from the menu with

```
.menu ul {
    display: none;
}
```

Then when the parent page is selected we use the css classes that are set by WordPress to show the sublists again.

```
.menu .current_page_ancestor, .menu .current_page_parent {
    display: block;
}
```

So all you need is this in your template

Template:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=') ?>
</ul>
```

and this in your css file.

CSS:

```
.menu ul {
    display: none;
}

.menu .current_page_ancestor > ul, .menu .current_page_parent > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I can't believe that was so easy, Thanks very much Horttcore